# Changing the amount of a 'Coin Pack' IAP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an IAP set up for an iOS game, that gives the player in-game currency for real money.  Right now I have the amount of in-game coins saved in the game, while the price is saved in the information Apple collected for the IAP.

The problem is, sometimes we might want to run special deals where instead of, say, 1000 coins the IAP would give the player 1500 coins if they bought it on a certain weekend.  If the amount of coins for the IAP is saved in the game, we're relying on the fact that players will update their app at the proper times to get the weekend deal and not everyone updates right away. On the other hand, we can change the IAP information given to Apple at any time so I was wondering:

Could I add a coin amount in the IAP 'description' field and use that to determine how much to give players?  Does it take time to get the IAP reviewed if the description gets changed?  Or is there a better way to set up an IAP so it is possible to change the amount of in-game coins it gives players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is to just change the price of the purchase during your deal time. That's what the app store is setup to do, it will be simple for you to do and 100% reliable.

Your hacky option of using the description will work (assuming you code it correctly). And technically, the user will see the updated description in the store while the deal is on. But you'll have much less control over the timing (as you say, due to the review time for each change).